# Update specific field in mongodb document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I using C# driver to use MongoDb in small projects, and now I stuck with updating documents.
trying to figure out how to update the field **AVG** (int)

here is my code:

```
IMongoCollection<Student> studentCollection = db.GetCollection<Student>("studentV1");

Student updatedStudent = new Student() { AVG = 100, FirstName = "Shmulik" });

studentCollection.UpdateOne(
        o=>o.FirstName == student.FirstName,
            **<What should I write here?>**);
```

there is simple and clean way to update specific field(s) like the method `ReplaceOne(updatedStudent)`?

Comment: I think you should read mongodb docs, it has covered all scenario related to update using c# driver. https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this..& [for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818964/how-do-you-update-multiple-field-using-update-set-in-mongodb-using-official-c-sh)

```
IMongoCollection<Student> studentCollection = db.GetCollection<Student>("studentV1");

Student updatedStudent = new Student() { AVG = 100, FirstName = "Shmulik" });

var update = Update<Student>.
Set(s => s.AVG, "500").
Set(s => s.FirstName, "New Name");
```

Comment: What's the role of the second line where updatedStudent is created?

Answer (score 46):

ok, so found out there is easy way to do it without write strings all over the code (Property names):

```
var updateDef = Builders<Student>.Update.Set(o => o.AVG, student.AVG);

studentCollection.UpdateOne(o => o.FirstName == student.FirstName, updateDef);
```

I didn't know it's take so long to find (+2 days), but I finally found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453681/mongo-update-array-element-net-driver-2-0)
with the lines:

```
var filter = Builders<TempAgenda>.Filter.Eq(x => x.AgendaId, agendaId);
var update = Builders<TempAgenda>.Update.Set(x => x.Items.Single(p => p.Id.Equals(itemId)).Title, title);
var result = _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Result;
```

and now it's much easier.

Comment: Agree on this as this is from the official documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/